# How would i show the username of the user after they login in react js and axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

```
app.post("/api/register", async(req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password

    connection.query(
        "INSERT INTO teacherlogins (name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)",
        [username, email, password],
        (err,result) => {
            console.log(err)
        }
    )


})
```

I have a server where the users data once they register is stored and I'd like to show their username in the top right corner after they login

```
const [showName, setShowName] = useState("")

    Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/register")
    .then((response) => {
        setShowName(response.data.username)
    })
    console.log(showName)
```

I then try to display the showName state in a

tag however it console logs with an empty string for some reason

Comment: I guess you will have to use your user infos in differents components of your app, so you should use react Context API, useReducer hook or even Redux to store global infos (like your user info) to be able to access these datas and update it through whole of your application.

Comment: @Ben What do you think is better to learn for a beginner out of those 3?

Comment: If you do not have to store many datas or a lot of data, I think that Context API is the simplest approach. UseReducer achieve quite the same thing Redux does, but I think it is a bit simpler. Or, as an alternative to Redux, you could use Easy Peasy https://easy-peasy.dev/. It achieve the same thing as Redux do, but I think it is simpler to start with, and then if you switch to Redux on another project it will be simpler to work with Redux :)

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the help I really appreciate it!